# Swift: How to get data from files in firebase Storage to a view in swiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I need help with a swift programming problem with the swiftUI framework. It is a social network, where at first you register or log in, the authentication is through firebase, then you fill out a form with your name, photo, biography among other things, and the information is sent to firebase and stored in firestore database, so far everything is fine, the authentication works and the data is stored correctly with the model (MVVM), the problem is that I have not found a way once I have the user information stored in Firestore, take that information a view in which the user's profile is displayed, could someone tell me how to achieve it please?

I'm new to swift and I still don't fully understand it, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Model

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Firebase

// MARK: - User Model
struct FirebaseUserModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var coverImage: String
    var profileImage: String
    var username: String
    var name: String
    var age: String
    var description: String
    var gender: String
}
```

Here is the firebaseViewModel class

```
class FirebaseViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data = [FirebaseUserModel]()
    
    // MARK: - Save info
    func saveInfoUser(coverImage: Data, profileImage: Data, username: String, name: String, age: String, description: String, gender: String, completion: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        let profileImageIDName = UUID()
        let coverImageIDName = UUID()
        
        let directoryProfileImage = storage.child("ProfileImages/\(profileImageIDName)")
        let directoryCoverImage = storage.child("CoverImages/\(coverImageIDName)")
        
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        
        metadata.contentType = "image/png"
        
        directoryProfileImage.putData(profileImage, metadata: metadata) { data, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Save profile photo correctly".uppercased())
            } else {
                if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                    print("Failed to save image to Storage", error)
                } else {
                    print("There was a bug in the app")
                }
            }
        }
        
        directoryCoverImage.putData(coverImage, metadata: metadata) { data, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Cover photo saved successfully".uppercased())
            } else {
                if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                    print("Error saving cover photo to Storage", error)
                } else {
                    print("There was a bug in the app")
                }
            }
        }
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        
        guard let idUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
        
        let fields: [String: Any] = ["coverImage": String(describing: directoryCoverImage), "profileImage": String(describing: directoryProfileImage), "username": username, "name": name, "age": age, "description": description, "gender": gender, "idUser": idUser, "email": email]
        
        db.collection(name).document(id).setData(fields) { error in
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                print("Error saving to firestore".uppercased(), error)
            } else {
                print("Data saved successfully")
                completion(true)
            }
        }
                
    }

    // MARK: - Show user information
    func getData(name: String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("name").addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                print("Error displaying user data", error)
            } else {
                self.data.removeAll()
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                    let value = document.data()
                    let id = document.documentID
                    let coverImage = value["coverImage"] as? String ?? "No cover image"
                    let profileImage = value["profileImage"] as? String ?? "No profile picture"
                    let username = value["username"] as? String ?? "No username"
                    let name = value["name"] as? String ?? "Unnamed"
                    let age = value["age"] as? String ?? "Ageless"
                    let description = value["description"] as? String ?? "Without description"
                    let gender = value["gender"] as? String ?? "Unknown gender"
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let records = FirebaseUserModel(id: id, coverImage: coverImage, profileImage: profileImage, username: username, name: name, age: age, description: description, gender: gender)
                        self.data.append(records)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to show user information in this Swiftui view, I have tried with several tutorials but I can't bring the data from Firebase. (The data are already in the Storage with all information and photos).

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you tried for getting the information into the `View`?

Comment: @jnpdx I bring the getData function of the FirebaseUser Model by means of a @StateObject `@StateObject var info = FirebaseViewModel()` The problem is that I don't know how to display it in a text or an image `Text(info.getData(name: ))`